# ScrollViewer with SizeToContent = WidthAndHeight

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have MyWindow where SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" in WPF. When MyWindow is bigger than screen I want to activate a ScrollViewer. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: post some xaml for proper resolution of problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use a... Scrollviewer.

some code for you:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Name="Window"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Green">
        <Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="red" MinWidth="600" MinHeight="400">
            <!--Some Content Here-->
            <Label>Foo</Label>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

What this code does:

- A Window with SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight, as wanted.
- A ScrollViewer that stretches with the window
- A Grid to put your content (could be a Canvas, or any kind of Panel). This grid as MinWidth and MinHeight set so that what is inside the grid will be able to stretch up but not down. So your content will initially be 600x400 (in this case) but will be able to stretch up. If you try to size it down to 300x200 for instance, you'll get your scrollbars.

this should at least get you started.